# why window gives access violation when we try to modify global constant

Tags: c++

Below code is actually for an embedded system where you can modify global constant. currently we are trying to simulate some part in windows.
when we try to modify global constant in windows in vs 2005 it gives us stackoverflow exception and in vs 2015 it gives us access violation issue.
i am giving small code here to give idea. Here second modification will produce error.I just want to know why window do not allow such modification ? 
Thanks in advance.

```
const int i = 5;

int main()
{
const int c = 10;
int* d = const_cast<int*>(&c);
*d = 20;
int* p = const_cast<int*>(&i);
*p = 20;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about what you are trying to do.  Can you modify something that is not modifiable?

Comment: In embedded its perfect in window we solve problem by using #define , just want to know why ?.

Comment: Maybe because modifying a constant is undefined?

Comment: Because different parts of your application are loaded into different memory pages with different permissions. When you try to write into read-only page, system throws segfault at you.

Comment: I do not believe the implicit claim here that this is a documented feature of the embedded system and its tool chain. You're writing buggy code and getting away with it because it isn't enforced.  Just because the machine lets you can change the constant doesn't mean all is well. You're lying to the compiler. What if the compiler decides to emit some code that assumes that the constant hasn't changed? The following could turn into an infinite loop  `while (i) { external_function(); }` even if `external_function` sets `i` to `0`.

Comment: @kaz well I am not embedded programmer but what I have come to know from my colleagues that by defining const to some variable in embedded system they make sure that it uses some different part of memory which also used by their hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both code snippets invoke undefined behavior: `const_cast<T>` cannot be used to cast away `const`-ness of something that is actually `const`. It can be used only to cast away `const`-ness of something that is *not* `const`, but is presented as `const` to your code.

For example, if you pass a `const` pointer to a non-const variable to a function, it would be legal for that function to cast away `const`-ness, and make a modification:

```
void foo(const int* p) {
    *(const_cast<int*>(p)) = 5;
}
```

However, if you were to pass a `const` pointer to something that is actually `const`, doing the same thing would trigger undefined behavior:

```
int main() {
    int good = 123;
    const int bad = 456;
    foo(&good); // Works
    foo(&bad);  // Undefined behavior
}
```

The reason this "works" in your particular embedded system is that undefined behavior does not, unfortunately, mean that the corresponding piece of code must fail. It just so happens that your embedded toolchain places constants into modifiable memory, so `const_cast`-ing a `const` pointer gives you a valid address to write. Doing the same thing would fail on systems that place constants into write-protected memory.

Comment: yep you are correct  , Here in windows I see it works for local variable but not for global I guess in linux  its segmentation fault. just want to know any specific reason for same like OS did not allow such area of memory for any write or something like that.

Comment: @vivek Undefined behavior is undefined. Anything can happen.

Comment: @vivek It's not OS-specific, it has to do with hardware capabilities and the way the compiler uses or ignores them. Some hardware lets OS mark memory segments read-only, triggering a trap each time a write into any such segment is attempted. The compiler may produce code that uses it, but the standard does not prohibit it from keeping everything in writable memory either. As the result of this choice, undefined behavior may give appearance of "working".